# How to set SCSS variables' values from Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I have gone through other same type of questions and couldn't get clarity. I have an API which give me primary and secondary colors. I have to dynamically set my `$primary` and `$secondary` colors in SCSS file based on that. Also, I'm using some Angular Material components and I want those colors should also be updated as my other parts of app. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you cannot. scss is pre-processed to css in build-time. you can use css variables though. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to overwrite the theme for change the primary and accent colors. Here you have a good example of to do it https://medium.com/@chrishouse/custom-material-theme-with-angular-5-f8ad0409bf44